# Google Tag Manager custom Javascript: "Unknown variable {{Click Id}}"

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to access Click event related variables in custom javascript.
Click event variables should be so called built-in variables but still it states unknown.

I'm using following syntax which is supposed to get ID of clicked link and return social media action per ID:

```
function() {
    var some = {{Click ID}};

    if (some == "tw")
        return 'tweet';
    else
        return 'share';
}
```

EDIT: For me it looks like I'm using variables just like on this page http://www.apasters.com/blog/google-tag-manager-custom-javascript-variable-examples/ but what is the problem?

Comment: can I just ask why there are no braces around your if statement?

Comment: There's no need for curly braces for single-line if statements, but I normally use them anyway for aesthetics, :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure that you have **enabled/activated** the built-in variables before you use them, otherwise you get that error message.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Now I realized that not all of them are "automagically" enabled and one must enabled them by checkboxes. Sadly, even the Google docs don't show this as a how to image or step by step list.